# Type 'Hotel' is missing the following properties from type 'Hotel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two properties

```
allHotels: Hotel[] = [];
filteredHotels: Hotel[] = [];
```

and i am filtering `allHotels` and assigning it to `filteredHotels`

```
this.filteredHotels = this.allHotels
          .find((hotel) => hotel.name.toLowerCase() === this.hotelFilterCtrl.value.toLowerCase());
```

but this is showing

```
Type 'Hotel' is missing the following properties from type 'Hotel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more
```

Hotel is of type

```
export class Hotel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I am bit confused what is the issue!!! Any help please!!!

Comment: You need to change `find` to `filter`.

Comment: This is a typo-level mistake. [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) finds the first element and returns it (a `Hotel`). You probably wanted [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (given the name `filteredHotels`), which returns an array of matching elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `find()` method the result is a single hotel, not an array as is the type you are trying to assign this result to. That is why you get this error.

If you want more than one hotel as a result use the `filter()` function instead.

Comment: oh yeah thanks!! by mistake i wrote find.. its been an hour m finding this silly mistake

Comment: Since this is a typo-level, it seems like rather than an *answer* (which when upvoted prevents the OP from deleting the question), a comment would be sufficient.

Comment: Good point, I'll think about that in the future. But I do think this question could be of value in the future when people encounter similar error messages.